# php glob not working on localhost XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, glob

I'm trying to get all php files from a certain folder on XAMPP. On my linux server I had no trouble using this code, but on my windows machine it seems impossible.

this is the path to the folder copied from my explorer:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\project\pages
```

This is my code:

```
$dirUserPath = dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))). "\pages";
$dirAdmin = glob($dirUserPath . "*.php");
var_dump($dirUserPath);
var_dump($dirAdmin);
```

And this is the result I get from this code:

```
string(29) "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\pages" array(0) { }
```

Glob is installed and there are php-files in the pages folder

Comment: Try to change `$dirUserPath = dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))). "\pages";` to `$dirUserPath = dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))). "\pages\";`

Comment: Welcome... .. :)